# check if not completed Observable is empty

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

Is there a good way to check if not completed Observable is empty at that exact time?

```
let cache = new ReplaySubject<number>(1);
...
// Here I want to know if 'cache' still empty or not. And, for example, fill it with initial value.
cache.isEmpty().subscribe(isEmpty => {
    if (isEmpty) {
        console.log("I want to be here!!!");
        cache.next(0);
    }
});
// but that code does not work until cache.complete()
```

Comment: An "empty" `Observable` isn't really a meaningful concept in this context, I think you are conflating concerns between the `Observer` and `Observable`. What is it you are trying to accomplish by this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `takeUntil()`:

```
Observable.of(true)
    .takeUntil(cache)
    .do(isEmpty => {
        if (isEmpty) {
            console.log("I want to be here!!!");
            cache.next(0);
        }
    })
    .subscribe();
```

However this will just work once.

---

Another way would be to "null" the cache and initialize it as empty by using a `BehaviorSubject`:

```
let cache = new BehaviorSubject<number>(null as any);
...
cache
   .do(content => {
       if (content == null) {
           console.log("I want to be here!!!");
           cache.next(0);
       }
    })
    .subscribe();
```

And of course you could initialize the cache with some default value right away.

Comment: Moreover, `BehaviorSubject` has a method [getValue](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/file/es6/BehaviorSubject.js.html#lineNumber21) that returns current value if any.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it's not that simple and the accepted answer is not very universal. You want to check whether `ReplaySubject` is empty at this particular point in time.

However, if you want to make this truly compatible with `ReplaySubject` **you need to take into account also `windowTime` parameter** that specifies *"time to live"* for each value that goes through this object. This means that whether your `cache` is empty or not **will change in time**.

`ReplaySubject` has method [`_trimBufferThenGetEvents`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/ReplaySubject.ts#L70) that does what you need. Unfortunately, this method is private so you need to make a little "hack" in JavaScript and extend its `prototype` directly.

```
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

// Tell the compiler there's a isNowEmpty() method
declare module "rxjs/ReplaySubject" {
    interface ReplaySubject<T> {
        isNowEmpty(): boolean;
    }
}

ReplaySubject.prototype['isNowEmpty'] = function() {
    let events = this._trimBufferThenGetEvents();
    return events.length > 0;
};
```

Then using this `ReplaySubject` is simple:

```
let s = new ReplaySubject<number>(1, 100);
s.next(3);
console.log(s.isNowEmpty());
s.next(4);

setTimeout(() => {
    s.next(5);
    s.subscribe(val => console.log('cached:', val));
    console.log(s.isNowEmpty());
}, 200);

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(s.isNowEmpty());
}, 400);
```

Note that some calls to `isNowEmpty()` return `true`, while others return `false`. For example the last one returns `false` because the value was invalidated in the meantime.

This example prints:

```
true
cached: 5
true
false
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/sutaka/3/edit?js,console

Comment: I was also looking at the `_trimBufferThenGetEvents()` function to achieve that, and it really seems to be the only way. It's a shame that this function is not exposed.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`.scan()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-scan) to accumulate your count, and map that to a boolean whether it's nonzero. (It takes a second parameter for a seed value which would make it start with a 0, so it always reflects the current count.)

I've also added a .filter() instead of an if statement to make it cleaner:

```
let cache = new ReplaySubject<number>(1);

cache
    .map((object: T) => 1)
    .scan((count: number, incoming: number) => count + incoming, 0)
    .map((sum) => sum == 0)
    .filter((isEmpty: boolean) => isEmpty)
    .subscribe((isEmpty: boolean) => {
        console.log("I want to be here!!!");
        cache.next(0);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

### startWith

```
let cache = new ReplaySubject<number>(1);

isEmpty$ = cache.pipe(mapTo(false), startWith(true));
```

This says:

- Whatever the value is emitted by cache - map it to `false`. (because it isn't empty after an emission)
- Start with `true` if nothing has been emitted yet (because that means it's empty)